# Passing information from Runnable to ScheduledJobThreadExecutor.afterExecute

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, threadpoolexecutor

I am scheduling periodic tasks and using the ScheduledJobThreadExecutor.
When executing the runnable, something might happen that requires my reaction, but It has to happen only after the task finishes.

At first I thought I will be able to access this information in aftetExecute, since I am getting a Runnable there (and than I could query its state). Turned out it is not the original runnable I submitted! But a ScheduledFutureTask, and I cant find a way to unwrap my original Runnable.

What can I do?
Is there an idiom for this kind of requirement?

Thank you!

Comment: Can't you create your own wrapper for Runnable which executes original Runnable first and then executes the desired reaction?

Comment: After giving it some thought, that is exactly what I did. I was wondering whether I could harness the built in extensibility hooks.